# JavaScript grammar notation

Tags: javascript, grammar, context-free-grammar

In the section 5.1.5 Grammar Notation of the ECMAScript there is an example of the grammar notation regarding to parameterized productions

> References to nonterminals on the right-hand side of a production can
> also be parameterized. For example:
>
> ```
> StatementList :
>     ReturnStatement
>     ExpressionStatement[+In]
> ```
>
> is equivalent to saying:
>
> ```
> StatementList :
>     ReturnStatement
>     ExpressionStatement_In
> ```

Should it be

```
StatementList :
    ReturnStatement
    ExpressionStatement
    ExpressionStatement_In
```

similarly to nonterminals on the left-hand side of productions?

Comment: No, it shouldn't.

Comment: JavaScript has one of the most complicated grammars of any modern language. Unless you really really want to know the details, it's a lot easier to simply not care.

Comment: @Pointy so your point is that we should just give up and write what we "think" is JavaScript instead?

Comment: I'd assume from the asking of this question that Vlad "really wants to know the details". "Who cares" isn't a very useful comment.

Comment: @Pointy I'd say it's still less complicated than C++, given that it's at least context-free :)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts and the construction mentioned in the question actually prevents JS form being context-sensitive :)

Comment: @JonasWilms yes :) No, but you know what I mean, the grammar is insane because of regular expression literals and modern stuff that's been added since 2015. Studying the grammar is *extremely* complicated.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts look at what regular expression literals do to the grammar. It's crazy complicated.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts also almost no modern language is truly "context free". Any language that insists on variables being declared, for example, is not "context free".

Comment: @Pointy And then add automatic semicolon insertion on top of that :-)

Comment: @Pointy of course runtime semantics aren't context free. I'm talking about grammars.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: ECMAScript's [early errors](https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0/#early-error) are not runtime semantic rules. ("An *early error* is an error that can be detected and reported prior to the evaluation of any construct... An implementation must report early errors in a *Script* **as part of parsing that *Script***" (some emphasis added). In other words, early errors are syntactic restrictions which cannot be described in a context-free grammar. (Or were not convenient to describe, but mostly they're not possible to describe in a CFG.)

Comment: @JonasWilms: However, bracketed non-terminals do not resolve any context-sensitive feature. Like `opt`, they are simply a way of allowing the context-free grammar to be written more compactly, with less repetition. (And, IMHO, they would be quite useful in a parser generator.) You can eliminate the brackets with a straight-forward preprocessing step, whose result is a much larger but still contex-free grammar.

Comment: @rici true but without distinguishing productions were in can and cannot appear, certain expressions would be ambigouos. By introducing the parameter In, this can be avoided whilst keeping the grammar at least slightly readable.

Comment: @Jonas: Yes, that's what I said. "Allowing the context-free grammar to be written more compactly." But they're not context-sensitive. They're just macros. *Every* context-free grammar defines where certain constructs can and cannot appear. That's what a grammar is. Context-sensitivity is when the expansion of a non-terminal is constrained by what happens to surround it, which is different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I think this is deliberate. It *adds* the parameter to the production. Although `ExpressionStatement_In` would be shorter, it would be even more confusing to mix parameterized and non parameterized non-terminals.

FWIW, the `In` parameter means (as noted in [13.10](https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0/#sec-relational-operators)):

> The [In] grammar parameter is needed to avoid confusing the in operator in a relational expression with the in operator in a for statement.

So `Expression[+In]` means the `in` operator can appear in the production and cannot lead to a syntactical ambiguity, whereas `Expression[~In]` means `in` may not appear in the expression, as it would be confused with the `for ... in`. Thus `for(a in b; false; ) { }` is a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

In the ECMAScript formalism, bracketed parameter lists are a form of macro expansion. Like any other macro facility, they do not actually carry any intrinsic semantic information. Brackets can be eliminated with a macro preprocessor, and such tools do exist.

Leaving aside the lookahead restrictions, there are three related but very different uses of brackets in the formalism's metasyntax:

1. On the left-hand side of a production, bracketed parameters indicate that the production is defining multiple non-terminals, whose names may (or may not) have `_parameter` appended. As you say, the definition

   ```
   ExpressionStatement[In] : ...
   ```

   would indicate that the (macro-expanded) grammar had two non-terminals, `ExpressionStatement` and `ExpressionStatement_In`. You can define a name with multiple parameters, in which case all the combinations are being defined. (And, in the current version of ECMA-262, `ExpressionStatement` is not actually qualified with an `In` parameter. Its actual definition is `Expression[Yield, Await]`, which is shorthand for four different non-terminals.)
2. That might lead you to believe that it would be OK to use `ExpressionStatement` or `ExpressionStatement_In` on the right-hand side of a production. And you could, technically, do that, since the notation is just a macro notation. But it would be quite confusing and the grammar does not ever do that. (There were earlier grammar drafts which did though, and some of the automated tools permit it. But it's better to pretend that once a non-terminal is defined with bracketed parameters, it must always be used with bracketed parameters, the same ones in the same order.)

   Fortunately, the real grammar uses explicit right-hand side parameters, which have three forms (remembering that there can be multiple parameters, so what's inside the brackets is actually a list). The three possibilities are:

   - `[+parameter]`, which is the same as appending `_parameter` to the non-terminal's name; i.e. an indication that the version of the non-terminal indicated is the one with the feature.
   - `[~parameter]`, which is technically a no-op, the same as nothing be appended to the name, indicating that the version indicated is the one without the feature.
   - `[?parameter]` is the same as either `[+parameter]` or `[~parameter]`, depending on whether the particular production being expanded was invoked with or without the `parameter`. This syntax can only be used if the non-terminal being defined and the non-terminal being used both have a parameter with the same name. But it's not required that they be the same non-terminal.
3. Finally, you can make particular alternatives conditional on a parameter (or a list of parameters) by putting a bracketed list at the beginning of the alternative. (In this position, it doesn't immediately follow the name of a non-terminal, so there is no ambiguity.) There are two possible conditions:

   - `[+parameter]`: the alternative is only included for the non-terminals (of the set being defined) which has that parameter.
   - `[-parameter]`: the alternative is only included for the non-terminals (of the set being defined) which does not have that parameter.

Note that, as an exception to the usual rule for grammars, which is that all non-terminals actually be used somewhere, the ECMAScript formalism does not require that every possible expansion of a parameterised non-terminal actually be reachable. So the correct way to macro-expand bracket notation is to start with the root non-terminals and traverse the tree of productions, creating individual instances of a bracketed non-terminal when its first use is encountered.

Comment: It might be easier to understand if they had chosen that `ExpressionStatement[In]` expands to `ExpressionStatement_In` and `ExpressionStatement_NoIn`

Comment: @Bergi: yeah, in retrospect there's lots of room for improvement. I still think it could make for a great feature. I use it a lot (with a preprocessor).

Comment: Generating every possible expansion of a parameterized production wouldn't be *incorrect*, it would just be somewhat inefficient.

Comment: @Michael: Most parser generators complain about unused non-terminals, so if you're doing it as a frontend preprocessor to some parser generator, you either need to get rid of them or not generate them in the first place.