# Understanding ECMAScript production parameterized annotations

Tags: javascript, regex, ecma262

I have been reading about how regular expressions are parsed in JS in this link: https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0/#sec-regular-expressions, but I don't quite understand what are the parameterized annotations `[N]` and `[Sep]`.

Like in this example:

[image]

If I am not wrong I think that the annotation `[UnicodeMode]` refers to the Unicode flag of the regexp.

Can someone guide me into what `[N]` and `[Sep]` means?

Comment: Does [JavaScript grammar notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73522554/1048572) help?

Comment: See https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0/#sec-parsepattern where those flags are used

Answer (score 1):

For how parameterised grammar productions work in general, see [JavaScript grammar notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73522554/1048572).

> If I am not wrong I think that the annotation `[UnicodeMode]` refers to the Unicode flag of the regexp.

Yes indeed, it is used in [*ParsePattern*](https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0/#sec-parsepattern) which is called both for regex literals and from the `RegExp` constructor, and the `UnicodeMode` grammar flag is set when the `/u` regex flag is given.

> Can someone guide me into what `[N]` means?

This flag is used to change the meaning of [named backreferences](https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html). If the regex contains at least one named group `(?<name>…)`, then `\k<name>` notation will refer to such groups (and a group with the given name must exist, according to early error static semantics). But if the regex does not use `(?<…>…)` anywhere, then `\k` will just be treated as an `IdentityEscape` (i.e. matching a literal `k` in the input text).

> What about `[Sep]`?

That's just a reference to the [`DecimalDigits` production](https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0/#prod-DecimalDigits) from the normal number literal grammar. It prevents the use of a `NumericLiteralSeparator` in the number, essentially making it a production matching only integer literals.