# What does +In mean in ECMAScript Grammatical Parameters?

Tags: javascript

In the ecmascript spec I have seen such examples and I don't understand what `+In` is supposed to mean.

> VariableStatement<sub>[Yield, Await]</sub> :
>
> var VariableDeclarationList<sub>[+In, ?Yield, ?Await]</sub> ;

The only information I have found was this article from the chrome v8 block, [understanding the ecmascript spec](https://v8.dev/blog/understanding-ecmascript-part-3), which states how the above example would expand. The article says

> On the right-hand side of the production, we see the shorthand +In, meaning "use the version with _In.

This does not at all explain what `_In` is supposed to mean in the first place. The article then shows how the above statement would expand. What is `VariableDeclarationList_In` referring to? Can anyone give javascript examples of each of these statements? If I can understand this it would help in understanding the spec a lot more since these are used so often.

> VariableStatement :
>
> var VariableDeclarationList_In ;
>
> VariableStatement_Yield :
>      var VariableDeclarationList_In_Yield ;
>
> VariableStatement_Await :
>      var VariableDeclarationList_In_Await ;
>
> VariableStatement_Yield_Await :
>      var VariableDeclarationList_In_Yield_Await ;

Comment: There's an entire chapter dedicated to explaining it: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-syntactic-and-lexical-grammars In particular, you're asking about [Grammatical Parameters](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-grammatical-parameters)

Comment: I read through that already, I also used `command + F` to see if there is anywhere in the spec explaining what `_In` means because it is used all over the place and I can't find it anywhere. There is a section explaining what `opt` is and then it starts using `[+In]` and never explains it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73522554/javascript-grammar-notation

Comment: "The [In] grammar parameter is needed to avoid confusing the in operator in a relational expression with the in operator in a for statement." That is the key I was missing, thanks. That answered the question.

Comment: "*There is a section explaining what `opt` is and then it starts using `[+In]` and never explains it.*" - skip over the [Optional Symbols section](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-optional-symbols) and read the [Grammatical Parameters section](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-grammatical-parameters) instead